# Undefined reference GCC compilation

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, gdb

I am new to Linux and I am trying to learn how to run and debug my programs using GCC and GDB. I set my Visual Studio Code to run and debug C/C++ programs and I wrote a simple code that implements a list. When I hit Run>Start Debugging in VSC everything works fine and the output is as expected.

However I want to compile my code using gcc and to debug it using gdb. When trying to compile using gcc I get the [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVKzx.png).

Comment: Use `g++` to compile C++ code.

Comment: Please don't post images: I currently am unable to view it, and therefore have no idea what you're talking about. Copy/pasting the text is arguably easier and faster than screen-grabbing, uploading, and linking an image as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `g++` to compile C++ code. `gcc` is for C code. The undefined references are the result of `gcc` not linking to the C++ standard library.